# For loop console.logs duplicates

Tags: javascript

**JS Code**

```
function generate(rectWidth, rectHeight, amount) {

// holds size
let size = {
    width: [],
    height: []
};

// holds colors
let colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    // generate size
    var width = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectWidth) + 1);
    var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectHeight) + 1);

    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

    // add size to object
    size.width.push(width);
    size.height.push(height);
    colors.push(`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);
}

return {
    size: size,
    colors: colors
};

};


function draw() {
var properties = generate(50, 50, 3);

if(properties) {

    for (let width = 0; width < properties.size.width.length; width++) {
        for (let height = 0; height < properties.size.height.length; height++) {
            for (let color = 0; color < properties.colors.length; color++) {

                console.log("Width: ", properties.size.width[width]);
                console.log("Height: ", properties.size.height[height]);
                console.log("Color: ", properties.colors[color]);

            }

        }
    }

    return true;

} else {
    return false;
}

};
```

**What I'm Getting**

```
Width:  13
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  13
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  13
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  13
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  13
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  13
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  13
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  13
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  13
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  19
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  19
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  19
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  19
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  19
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  19
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  19
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  19
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  19
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  33
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  33
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  33
Height:  36
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  33
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  33
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  33
Height:  13
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)

Width:  33
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(141, 126, 60)

Width:  33
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(250, 94, 157)

Width:  33
Height:  42
Color:  rgb(249, 52, 206)
```

**Problem**

My problem is that I have a `for loop` that loops through `properties.sizes.width`, `properties.sizes.height`, `properties.colors`, than my program `console.log()`'s the values. The issue is that my `console.log()` should've output the width, height, and color 3 times (I gave 3 as a parameter in my `generate()`). But when I `console.log()`

Comment: It depends on **exactly** what you're trying to log, but you're getting duplicates because you're running `console.log()` from inside a for loop, inside another for loop. You'll need to tweak your code so that you can get the desired results while only logging in the **outermost** for loop :)

Comment: Seems all arrays would have same length...why 2 inner loops?

Comment: I need to loop through all the arrays, because I'm gonna draw rectangles in the canvas using the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one loop only:

```
for (let i= 0; i < properties.size.width.length; i++) {
    console.log("Width: ", properties.size.width[i]);
    console.log("Height: ", properties.size.height[i]);
    console.log("Color: ", properties.colors[i]);
}
```

I would however suggest a different structure, where you put all three properties that belong together in the *same* object, and add such objects to *one* array:

```js
function generate(rectWidth, rectHeight, amount) {
    // holds everything
    let result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        // generate size
        var width = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectWidth) + 1);
        var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectHeight) + 1);

        var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
        var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
        var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

        // add all to one object, and push it to the result array
        var color = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
        result.push({width, height, color});
    }
    return result;
};


function draw() {
    var properties = generate(50, 50, 3);
    properties.forEach(function (prop) {
        console.log("Width: ", prop.width);
        console.log("Height: ", prop.height);
        console.log("Color: ", prop.color);
    });
    return true;
};

draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your draw function to loop so it only loops the number of times you specify in amount (3 in your example):

```
function draw() {
    var amount = 3;
    var properties = generate(50, 50, amount);

    if(properties) {

        for (let i= 0; i< amount; i++) {
                    console.log("Width: ", properties.size.width[i]);
                    console.log("Height: ", properties.size.height[i]);
                    console.log("Color: ", properties.colors[i]);


        }

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

};
```